# Bread Crumb on XPM is different from actual page directory structure on CME

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

I publish index page on the following directory structure on CME.(refer to the follow image.)

So, Bread Crumb on CME is the follow.

**03 Site Master → root → news → index**

[image]

But Bread Crumb on XPM is the follow. (refer to the follow image.)

**03 Site Master → root → WEB-INF → Header**

[image]

I publish index page. But Bread Crumb on XPM show Header page.
But the page displayed on XPM is index page.
(index page include header page.)

So, Why is Bread Crumb on XPM different from actual page directory structure on CME?
am I mistake about Configuration ?

**UPDATE**

The Page Template (This PT is used by index page) is shown.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="cd_tags" prefix="tridion" %>
<%@ taglib uri="cd_tags" prefix="news" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ja" xml:lang="ja">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
  <title>news</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="news" />
  <meta name="description" content="news" />
  <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/design_elements.jsp" %>
  <script language="javascript">AC_FL_RunContent = 0;</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function sub_win() {
window.open('info/message.html', 'mywindow', 'width=650, height=600, menubar=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes');
}
// --></script>


</head>

<body class="press">
<div id="wrapper">
  <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/header.jsp" %>

<div id="main">
  <div id="contents-area">

<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="SubVisualComponents" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->

<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="TopLinkComponents" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->

<div id="contents">
<div class="section">

<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="GeneralHeadingComponents" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->

<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="CaseAgeCategoryComponents" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->

<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="NewsSummaryListComponents" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->

<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="NewsDetailComponents" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->

<!-- /.section --></div>
<!-- /#contents --></div>
<!-- /#contents-area --></div>

<p class="page-top"><a href="#header">return top</a></p>
<!-- /#main --></div>
  <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/footer.jsp" %>
<!-- /#wrapper --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I open source code about index page.
I found three important MarkUP(Maybe you answer about)

The following PT is Header PT.

```
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:22-1042-64","PageModified":"2014-03-07T13:54:40","PageTemplateID":"tcm:22-1041-128","PageTemplateModified":"2014-03-07T18:00:33"} -->
```

The following PT is Footer PT.

```
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:22-1046-64","PageModified":"2014-03-07T14:10:20","PageTemplateID":"tcm:22-1045-128","PageTemplateModified":"2014-03-07T16:18:29"} -->
```

**The following PT is the PT for index page.**

```
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:22-1370-64","PageModified":"2014-04-02T16:09:36","PageTemplateID":"tcm:22-1111-128","PageTemplateModified":"2014-03-24T17:06:46"} -->
```

Maybe Markup about header PT is topmost. So Breadcurmb on XPM is show header page.
So I remove two markup. is that right ?

Comment: When `Header` shows as the breadcrumb in XPM, what page does XPM open? Is the Header page also enabled for XPM--can you edit it on its own (meaning it includes the SiteEdit script)? There's nothing preventing a Tridion page from "including" another in delivery, but it's not a typical setup. If you can still edit though, you might not have an issue.

Comment: I'm guessing your index page includes the XPM markup for both pages. But to get a definitive answer, please provide at least the (XPM-related) markup of your Index page (as it exists on the server or simply what was published).

Comment: @ Alvin Reyes..... I open index page(/root/news/index.jsp) on XPM. But breadcrumb on XPM shows header(/root/WEB-INF/header.jsp).  Because Header page exists WEB-INF directory, Header page can't be displayed to web site. So I can't edit header page on XPM.

Comment: Thanks for showing your page output and showing your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my comments, but based on your description your Index page which "includes" the header page shows XPM markup for both (or possibly just the header). When you click on the page, the breadcrumb updates based on what you've selected (component presentations or page).

The fix could be not making the header page XPM-enabled or not implementing it as a Tridion page on its own (e.g. maybe as a dynamic component presentation referenced by your Index page's template).

Comment: Exactly, having the XPM Page Settings markup (with different URIs) multiple times on a single page is certainly going to mess things up. Disabling XPM editing of the include Pages would be the best solution. You can still keep XPM markup for any Component Presentations on there, that should still be fine.

Comment: @Bart Koopman -   Thank you to answer my question . I will be able to solve my problem.

Comment: @Alvin Reyes -    Thank you to answer my question . I will be able to solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I disabling XPM editing of the include Pages(for example, Header). (refer to the following image)

And I remove "Enable inline editing for Page" TBB from Header PT.

By above operations, I did solve!

[image]